# qbs get directory where a library is located

Tags: qt, qt5, qbs

I have a Product:

**demo.qbs**

```
import qbs

Product {
    Depends { name: "the_library" }
}
```

directory the_library_set and qbs for the libraries:
**the_library_set.qbs**

```
import qbs

Project {
    name: "the_library_set"
    qbsSearchPaths: "qbs"

    references: [
        "the_library/the_library.qbs",
        ...
    ]
```

**the_library.qbs**

```
Product {
    Depends { name: "the_module" }
}
```

**the_module.qbs**

```
import qbs

Module {        
    Properties {
        // I need the path relative to the the_library_set.qbs' dir here:
        cpp.includePaths: [?]
        cpp.libraryPaths: [?]
    }
}
```

How can I get the path relative to the the_library_set.qbs' file dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems dubious, because a module should in general not be making assumptions about the products depending on it, and especially not their locations. Likely, the respective project is ill-designed.
Ignoring that issue, the path you want is accessible via product.sourceDirectory.

Comment: is there a way to get the current .qbs file location in qbs?

Comment: Yes, via the path variable.